# Correct use of the word communication or communicating

Tags: word-choice, gerunds

Which one is correct:

> I have been **in communication** with your son...

or

> I have been **communicating** with your son...

Comment: is there something wrong with 'in talks' or 'talking'? 'communication' is VERY formal.

Answer (score 1):

In general, they're equivalent. Both your examples are using the correct tenses ("have been"). I think you'll be fine either way. If you'd like to post more context, I can give a more detailed response.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct with nuanced differences.

Saying that you have "been in communication" with someone implies that you have spoken to that person at least once. It could be more than once, but the last communication may or may not be recent.

Saying that you have "been communicating" with someone implies a continuous action, that you still have access to a way to communicate again, and that you are completely up-to-date on whatever the son might have to say.